# What is the expected error when storing decimals as single floats?

Tags: c++, floating-point, floating-point-precision, decimal-point

I'm looking at a c++ task which reads a file that contains decimal numbers and stores each number in a data structure as a single 4-byte `float`. Before changing the process (to use `double`) I want to know what is the average error in % between the number in the file and the number stored in the structure.

For example, if the file reads `19.5` and the data structure is `19.49999999` then the error is

```
abs(19.49999999 / 19.5 - 1) = 5.128205128205128e-8 %
```

If the distribution matters, most of the numbers in the file are positive and less than 1000.

Comment: Do you want us to give you an estimate of what the number will be? Or do you want us to tell you how to write a program to actually measure it? Or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

32-bit floats have 23 bits of mantissa, which means a representation accurate to about 7-8 decimal digits. To be precise, the relative error is `2^-24`, or about `6e-8`.

Comment: To understand the math, 2^-23 is the worst error and 2^-24 is the average error?

Comment: No, I believe 2^-24 is the worst error. The mathematically precise result is an infinite binary fraction. A `float` value holds the first 23 bits of this fraction, properly rounded. So the worst error is half of the value of the 23-rd bit, which is 2^-24. But must I admit I could very well be off. For underlying theory, see ["What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic"](http://www.validlab.com/goldberg/paper.pdf)

Comment: The result should indeed be correctly rounded. Reading a decimal input and rounding it to the correct binary fraction isn't trivial, but it's not unreasonably hard either.